# Prevent content to move down when displaying an output

Tags: html, button

I know is a simple question, but I got stuck again.
I have a button on a website I'm creating that displays the current month, the problem is that I'm not able to find a way to not move the contents when I press the button to display the month.
I want to make sure there is a space under the button that will display the month but it won't move the "Let's get started" down. Is there any way to do that?

```js
function myMonth() {
        var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June";
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December";
        var d = new Date();
        var n = month[d.getMonth()];
        document.getElementById("monthpick").innerHTML = n;
        }
```

```css
#monthpick{
  text-align: center;
  color: #008CBA;
}

.button {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;


}

.button1 {
  background-color: white; 
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
    
        <div class="monthpicker">
        <br>   
        <p><button onclick="myMonth()" class="button button1">Month</button></p>
        <h2 id="monthpick"></h2>
        <br>
        </div>

        <div class="begin">
        <h2>Let's get started!!!</h2>
        </div>

        
        
       
   
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the "Let's get started!!!" line is pushed down when the month is displayed is because initially the `<h2>` element which is used to hold the month is empty, thus its content height is 0. When the button is clicked, the month gets inserted into the `<h2>` which now needs a space(width & height) to display the content, and the "Let's get started!!!" line will be pushed down. The solution is simple: insert a whitespace as the content for the `<h2>` element as placeholder like this:

```
<h2 id="monthpick">&nbsp;</h2>
```

With this you'll see the gap between the button and the "Let's get started!!!" will be bigger. You can adjust the margins(top & bottom) of the month `h2` element to get a better spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a pre-defined height to your `monthpick` element, so that the text below it doesn't need to move once text is added.

It would mean, however, that any elements below will seem out of place until the text is generated, although - as you requested - it would definitely prevent text below from moving.

You could try adding something such as `height: 1px;` to your `monthpick` element, or simply provide the actual height (28px with the font size being generated) and work from there. Both should work as you intended.